# Is it possible for a MongoDB connection to timeout in Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, heroku

(Newbie question, sorry about that -I'm just beginning with MongoDB)

I am connecting to mongo on heroku like this:

```
self.connection = pymongo.Connection(MONGO_URL)
self.db = self.connection.app13805318
```

Is it possible that I try to use self.db after a few hours and can't read it? Do I need to do some kind of keepalive or refresh of the connection?

Comment: I believe the best practice here would be to catch any connection failures and retry on failure. See the following for pymongo exceptions, I would guess that AutoReconnect and ConnectionFailure would be important for client to mongo connection errors. OperationFailure as well can be thrown when a mongo to mongo socket exception is encountered. http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/errors.html

Comment: Thanks @JamesWahlin! i will do as you suggest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Citing from Pymongo documentation: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient

> The client object is thread-safe and has connection-pooling built in. If an operation fails because of a network error, ConnectionFailure is raised and the client reconnects in the background. Application code should handle this exception (recognizing that the operation failed) and then continue to execute.

So as @james-wahlin suggested in comments, you should not solely rely on pymongo's connection-pooling mechanism but always wrap your usage of `self.db` in `try..except` clauses.

Hope this helps.